# Form's resx file contains Point/Size and other weird UI objects

Tags: c#, resx, initializecomponent

For some reason one of our forms reads all UI element data from its corresponding resx file. We want all data to be explicitly assigned in the code instead.

E.g. Our resx file contains the location of our forms buttons:
Name: radioButton1.Location
Type: System.Drawing.Point
Value: 7; 68

In `InitializeComponent`, the data is then loaded by the [ApplyResources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.componentresourcemanager.applyresources.aspx) function:

```
resources.ApplyResources(this.radioButton1, "radioButton1");
```

For this project, this is unnecessary. We want to assign the UI data without reading some bloated resource file!

**Q: How did this resource binding occur and how do we revert it to the standard behavior?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the form's `Localizable` property to false solved the issue.